# Probability that $X \geq 3=?$

Tags: probability

### Question

> A fair die is tossed repeatedly until a six is obtained.  Let $X$ denotes the number of tosses required.

Probability that $X \geq 3=?$

### Approach

Although if I solve it using straight forward method -:

$$P(X \geq 3)=\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times  \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}+...$$

$$=c \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{1-\frac{5}{6}}(\text{By using GP of infinite series})$$

$$=\frac{25}{36}$$ and is correct.

But when I try to solve it using complement property, I am getting a different answer
$$P(X \geq 3)=1-P(X \geq 2)-P(X \geq 1)$$

$$=1-\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} -\frac{1}{6} =\frac{30}{36} $$

Where am I going wrong?
Please help.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is basic arithmetic, not probability theory.

Comment: $\frac 16=\frac {6}{36}$.  Worth noting:  in order that this take at least $3$ tries all that is needed is for the first two tries to fail.  Thus the answer is $\left( \frac 56 \right)^2=\frac {25}{36}$.

Comment: How do you get "_a six_" from tossing a _fair coin_??

Comment: that was a blunder typo .thanks updated!

Answer (score 3):

The second method is wrong.

$P(X \ge 3)=1-P(X=2)-P(X=1)=1-\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} -\frac{1}{6} =\frac{36}{36}-\frac{5}{36} -\frac{6}{36} =\frac{25}{36}$

A simple caculation mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your complement property is wrong: if you are calculating the property of getting $X$ more than some $n$-times, the complement property is getting $X$ *less* than $n$-times or, to put it in another way, the probability of *not* getting $X$ more that $n$-times. In the end what are you trying to accomplish is the following $$P(X\geq 3) = 1-P(X\lt 3)\\ = 1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$$